# Can't ping domain-member desktop PC from non-domain-member laptop

Tags: windows, networking, input-director

I'm trying to install Input Director as a master on my work desktop, and slave on my private laptop.  Both are on the same wired network, but my laptop cannot join the domain as it is Windows 7 Home Premium.  However I doubt this is a domain issue.

My desktop computer name is *xyz*, domain name *smartec.co.za*, full computer name is *xyz.smartec.co.za*.  From my laptop I get no ping replies from *xyz* or *xyz.smartec.co.za*.  What do I need to be able to see my computer name from my laptop?

I can't use a direct IP address as I'm on DHCP even on the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two PCs are on the same IP network (check IP address and network mask via ipconfig /all) and you got no replies to ping using the IPs it could be hardware problem or a firewall. If ping works with the IPs but no with the host names it could be a DNS problem. If ping works with host names but you can't see the other PC you could try using the name anyway, sometimes a reachable computer its not visible on the network due to computer browser or network configuration problems/settings.

Comment: Was a firewall issue indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible because of group policy applied to the system. This is very common for security reasons. Check out this Microsoft TechNet page for [Domain Isolation with Microsoft Windows Explained](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772960(WS.10).aspx).

These days, its all about security. Companies have to protect its customers information and its own interests.